# How can I solve the issue where VS code highlight for errors that don't exist only to remove the highlight on save?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

am using php I have the common extensions added but i just cant remove this annoying bug that highlights for errors on lines which have none, with no fixes annotated:  only for the highlight to disappear on save.

Comment: Specify the exact extensions you're using.

Comment: Many linters, like eslint, have an option to run `onSave` or `onType`.  [Eslint's default is `onType`].  Check whichever linter you are using for a similar option and see if `onSave` is better for you.

Comment: yeap thank you that was actually the issue mehn, though I was using it without any additional extensions. But now with extensions some have that option as u said. However I now understand most default to onSave for performance purposes.  post it as answer please. Am really sorry for the late reply